# Create my own loss without interrupting the gradient chain registered by the gradient tape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm learning Tensorflow 2.10, with Python 3.7.7.

I'm trying to use the tutorial "[Tensorflow - Custom training: walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough)" to use my own loss function.

This is my first version of loss function, and it works:

```
    def loss(model, x, y):
      output = model(x)
      return tf.norm(y - output)
```

I have changed to try another one, and it doesn't work:

```
def my_loss(model, x, y):
  output = model(x)

  # Only valid values for output var are 0.0 and 1.0.
  output_np = np.array(output)
  output_np[output_np >= 0.5] = 1.0
  output_np[output_np < 0.5] = 0.0

  # Counts how many 1.0 are on y var.
  unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
  dict_wmh = dict(zip(unique, counts))  
  wmh_count = 0
  if 1.0 in dict_wmh:
    wmh_count = dict_wmh[1.0]

  # Add y and output to get another array.
  c = y + output_np
  unique, counts = np.unique(c, return_counts=True)
  dict_net = dict(zip(unique, counts))

  # Counts how many 2.0 are on this new array.
  net_count = 0
  if 2.0 in dict_net:
    net_count = dict_net[2.0]

  # Return the different between the number of ones in the label and the network output.
  return wmh_count - net_count
  #return tf.convert_to_tensor(wmh_count - net_count, dtype=tf.float32)
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert value 0 to a TensorFlow DType.

If I change the return with this one:

```
return tf.convert_to_tensor(wmh_count - net_count, dtype=tf.float32)
```

I get the error:

> No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv1_1/kernel:0',
>   'conv1_1/bias:0', ...

On this function:

```
def grad(model, inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(model.trainable_variables)
        #loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
        loss_value = my_loss(model, inputs, targets)

    return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
```

Because I have asked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191618/tf-gradienttape-doesnt-return-gradients), now I know that my new loss function "[interrupts the gradient chain registered by the gradient tape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191901/68571)".

This new loss function (my_loss) does the following:

1. Converts the output of the model into an array which values are 0.0 or 1.0.
2. Create a new array adding this `output` to the `y` (which values are also 0.0 or 1.0).
3. Counts how many 2.0 are this new array.
4. Counts how many 1.0 are in the `y` array.
5. Returns the different between point 3 and 4.

How can I convert this into Tensors to not "[interrupts the gradient chain registered by the gradient tape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191901/68571)"?

Maybe there is a native function to do what I am trying to do.

By the way, I have convert it to numpy arrays because I can't do this, `output_np[output_np >= 0.5] = 1.0`, with Tensors.

Comment: You have to implement a loss function using tensorflow functions, not numpy, symbolic gradient will not propagate through non-tensorflow functions.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm looking for those functions in Tensorflow's documentation but I can't find how to do this `output_np[output_np >= 0.5] = 1.0` with Tensorflow functions. Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy And I'm not sure about this: "All tensors are immutable like python numbers and strings: you can never update the contents of a tensor, only create a new one." If I create a new tensor, I hope it won't interrupt the gradient chain.