# how to count how many times appear a value on a 2D Tensor: UniqueWithCounts only supports 1D Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, conv-neural-network

I'm learning Tensorflow 2.10, with Python 3.7.7.

I'm trying to use the tutorial "[Tensorflow - Custom training: walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough)" to use my own loss function.

This is my first version of loss function, and it works:

```
def loss(model, x, y):
  output = model(x)
  return tf.norm(y - output)
```

I have changed to try another one, and it doesn't work:

```
def my_loss(model, x, y):
  output = model(x)

  # Only valid values for output var are 0.0 and 1.0.
  output_np = np.array(output)
  output_np[output_np >= 0.5] = 1.0
  output_np[output_np < 0.5] = 0.0

  # Counts how many 1.0 are on y var.
  unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
  dict_wmh = dict(zip(unique, counts))  
  wmh_count = 0
  if 1.0 in dict_wmh:
    wmh_count = dict_wmh[1.0]

  # Add y and output to get another array.
  c = y + output_np
  unique, counts = np.unique(c, return_counts=True)
  dict_net = dict(zip(unique, counts))

  # Counts how many 2.0 are on this new array.
  net_count = 0
  if 2.0 in dict_net:
    net_count = dict_net[2.0]

  # Return the different between the number of ones in the label and the network output.
  return wmh_count - net_count
```

But I can use it because my new loss function "[interrupts the gradient chain registered by the gradient tape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191901/68571)".

So, I have tried to use only Tensorflow Tensor:

```
def my_loss_tensor(model, x, y):
  output = model(x)

  # Only valid values for output var are 0.0 and 1.0.
  output = tf.math.round(output)
  output = tf.clip_by_value(output, clip_value_min=0.0, clip_value_max=1.0)

  # Counts how many 1.0 are on y var (WMH mask).
  y_ele, y_idx, y_count = tf.unique_with_counts(y)

  # Add output to WMH mask.
  sum = tf.math.add(output, y)

  # Counts how many 2.0 are on the sum.
  sum_ele, sum_idx, sum_count = tf.unique_with_counts(sum)

  return tf.math.subtract(sum_count[sum_ele == 1.0], y_count[y_ele == 2.0])
```

`x` is a `tf.Tensor([[[[...]]]], shape=(1, 200, 200, 1), dtype=float32)`
`y` is a `tf.Tensor([[[[...]]]], shape=(1, 200, 200, 1), dtype=float32)`

They are images `(200x200x1)`.

I get the following error:

> unique expects a 1D vector. [Op:UniqueWithCounts]

Any idea about how to count how many times appear a value on a Tensor?

The real image data are on the `200x200` dimensions, the other two are used on my CNN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf.reshape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) method inside the loss to convert it to 1d vector:

```
out_flat = tf.reshape(output,[-1])
y_ele, y_idx, y_count = tf.unique_with_counts(out_flat)
```